# Unable to read from the stream in java

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

I am using **tcp socket** for client server programming in **java**. After  writing a message in the **outputstream**, I started to read the **inputstream** and I continues the reading till the inputstream returns -1(EOF). But its not returning -1, I got stucked. Please give your suggestions. Look at the code below.

```
int bytesRead = tcpSocket.readPacket(buffer);
while(bytesRead != -1) {
    builder.append(new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
    bytesRead = tcpSocket.readPacket(buffer);
}
```

Comment: How did you set up the `tcpSocket`? What is sending information to the socket?

Comment: What classes are you using - i.e. What is the type of `tcpSocket`?

Comment: I setup the tcp socket using server's ip address and port number. I am sending the information in xml format.

Comment: If this program is client, server must close outputstream after wrote response.  Or server returns content length and client must read exactly the size of bytes.

Comment: @user2570465 I am using socket.class in java, for connection, reading and writing from streams

Comment: @saka1029 you are right. In my case server only sends the response and its not closing the outputstream. Is there any other option

Answer (score 0):

If its a Socket then -1 would be returned when the connection is terminated (normally).

In your case, I would guess that there is no further data coming through but it is not returning -1 either.

Comment: While debugging, when the debugger reach this line,                                n = socketRead0(fd, b, off, length, impl.getTimeout()) the socketRead0 method returns nothing, the debugger vanishes.

Comment: The 'debugger vanishes' because there is no further execution - the call blocks.  If any more data was to be received, or the connection closed by the peer, the debugger would resume on the next line.